# How is the spin angular momentum $h/4\pi$ determined?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

We can determine the orbital angular momentum by $mvr$, how is the intrinsic spin angular momentum of an electron?

Comment: Did you read this article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(physics)  or any material related to the early history of spin, as an idea  to explain experimental results?

Comment: You should first take it as an experimental fact. Have a look at the Stern-Gerlach experiment. Later on, Dirac arrived at the spin in a natural way combining relativity with QM.

Answer (score 1):

Spin is a complicated matter that requires a bit of sophisticated mathematics to understand fully. I'll do my best to give a brief overview. The idea of spin is intimately related to the idea of *group representations*. The Hilbert space of every particle carries a (projective) representation of the rotation group $SO(3)$. (Or if you prefer, a standard representation of the double cover SU(2) which is what you will usually see in these discussions. I find it more intuitive to think about the actually 3 dimensional rotation symmetry.) From pure mathematics relating nothing to spin or angular momentum, we find that the representations of this group are defined by either an integer, or a half-integer. In physical language, this means roughly that the angular momentum of a quantum-mechanical particle, either spin or orbital, is either an integer or half-integer multiple of $\hbar$.

The representations of the group $SO(3)$ are the linear operators on the space of states that we have come to call the "angular momentum operators". One particular representation gives us the operators for spin $1/2$ particles
$$
S_x = \frac{\hbar}{2} \sigma_x, \quad S_y = \frac{\hbar}{2} \sigma_y, \quad S_z = \frac{\hbar}{2} \sigma_z, \quad  
$$
where the $\sigma_i$ are the *Pauli spin matrices*. These operators act on a state, denoted $|{s,m_s}\rangle$ and "return" the spin of the particle. I.e,
$$
S_z |{s,m_s}\rangle = \hbar m_s |{s,m_s}\rangle
$$
In the case of spin 1/2 particles, $m_s = \pm1/2$. Hence, we find that the spin of an electron for example is $\pm \frac{\hbar}{2}$, or as you wrote it, $\frac{h}{4\pi}$. I would be happy to elaborate more if you are interested in seeing more of the mathematics behind this explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The orbital angular momentum is determined by $L=\sqrt{1\left( l+1\right) }\cdot \dfrac{h}{2\pi }$, where $l$ is the azimuthal quantum number and the spin angular momentum is determined by $S=\sqrt{s\left( s+1\right) }\cdot \dfrac{h}{2\pi }$, where $s$ is the spin quantum number.