# Spin angular momentum?

Tags: angular-momentum, electrons, quantum-spin

An electron spins around its axis and magnetic field is produced. It can spin either in clockwise $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ or in counterclockwise $\left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)$ direction.

The spin angular momentum is given by $S=\sqrt{s\left( s+1\right) }\cdot \dfrac{h}{2\pi }$.

If $s$ is $\frac{1}{2}$, then the spin angular momentum is $\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{2}\left( \dfrac{1}{2}+1\right) }\cdot \dfrac{h}{2\pi }=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cdot \dfrac{h}{2\pi }$

and If $s$ is $\frac{-1}{2}$, then the spin angular momentum is $\sqrt{\dfrac{-1}{2}\left( -\dfrac{1}{2}+1\right) }\cdot \dfrac{h}{2\pi }=\dfrac{i}{2}\cdot \dfrac{h}{2\pi }$.

Why is the spin angular momentum of $s=\frac{-1}{2}$ imaginary value, is this possible? What is the meaning of this; what does it mean physically when particles have spin half and negative half integer and their spin angular momentum real or imaginary?

Comment: "the electron spins around its axis..." I beg you, tell me you know it's wrong.

Comment: Intrinsic total spin angular momentum of the electron at rest is always  ~0.866ℏ independent of its spin z-axis component direction, spin up +1/2 or spin down -1/2.

Comment: Reading list: 1.https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/365784/spin-angular-momentum-question 2.https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/296000/how-is-the-spin-angular-momentum-h-4-pi-determined/ 3.https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/614941/what-is-the-difference-between-angular-momentum-of-electron-by-bohr-and-orbital

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing the square of the spin vector
($\vec{S}^2$) with its 3 vector components ($S_x, S_y, S_z$).

The square of the spin $\vec{S}^2$ always has the value $s(s+1)\hbar^2$, which is positive.
And the electron has $s=\frac 12$ (no negative sign).

The components $S_x$, $S_y$ and $S_z$ each have two possible values
(a positive and a negative). These are
$+\frac 12 \hbar$ and $-\frac 12 \hbar$.